# AWS Lambda -> DAX -> DynamoDB: 'Client does not have permission to invoke Endpoints'

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

We are trying to enable the DAX for use in our NodeJS Lambdas. We have created the VPC, added DAX and Lambda into the VPC however now when the lambda function throws an error:

```
Failed to pull from xxxxx (xxx.xx.xx.122): { Error: Client does not have permission to invoke Endpoints
code: undefined,
retryable: false,
requestId: null,
statusCode: -1,
_tubeInvalid: true,
waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying: false,
_message: 'Client does not have permission to invoke Endpoints',
codeSeq: [ 4, 23, 31, 34 ],
cancellationReasons: undefined }
```

This is the Lambda code:

```
const daxOptions = {
  endpoint: 'xxx.apse2.cache.amazonaws.com:8111',
  region: 'ap-southeast-2',
};
const daxClient = new AmazonDaxClient(daxOptions);
const dynamoDb = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ service: daxClient, convertEmptyValues: true });

...

const payload = {
  RequestItems: {
    ['tableName']: {
      Keys: items.map(itemId => ({
        id: itemId,
      })),
    },
  },
};
const response = await dynamoDb.batchGet(payload).promise();
```

The DAX cluster seems to be working fine. We can list DAX clusters using: `aws dax describe-clusters --r ap-southeast-2 --profile tst`

Comment: Can you check that you have any dax: permissions on your policy associated with the lambda function?

Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733885/getting-permissions-exception-when-calling-amazondax-service/53734194#53734194

Comment: Did you mean something like this:
        {
            "Action": [
                "dax:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dax:ap-southeast-2:887018866993:cache/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElhaddad I found only docs about the service role https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.access-control.html but no word about the permissions for the actual lamdba that runs the code that is trying to connect to DAX.

Comment: Yes. See "IAM Policy to Allow DAX Cluster Access" section in the doc you linked

Comment: Permissions were configured according the doc. No luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I solve it.
There are 2 permissions involved. DAX to DynamoDB and client to run the CRUD operations.

Step 1. Delete the DAX cluster that you created. It was probably faulty. Lets start with a clean DAX cluster.

Step 2. When creating the cluster, enter these details

- IAM Service role for DynamoDB access -> Create New
- IAM role name -> enter a new unique role name, maybe "jeffb-dax-09-role"
- IAM policy name -> enter a new unique policy name, maybe "jeffb-dax-09-policy"
- IAM role policy -> "Read/Write"
- Target DynamoDB table -> All tables (customize later using IAM console)

Step 3. create another role with "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" policy, lets call it "jeffb-dynamodb-role"

Step 4. Use "jeffb-dynamodb-role" for the role in your client.

It worked for me.

Comment: You should never use the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy for this. It is WAY too wide open. A new customer managed IAM policy should always be used.